# WaitAttribute in selenium using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to put a waiting line for an element that appears for a while then disappears so I want to just wait till this element is gone
Here is the html for this hidden element

```html
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress3" style="display: none; text-align: center;" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
 
                                    <img src="images/17.gif">
                                
</div>
```

and I tried this line

```
bot.FindElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_UpdateProgress3").WaitAttribute "style", "display: none;", 15000
```

But the line executes and doesn't wait for the element to disappear...
The element is like Refresh that loads some results so I need a way to wait till this element is gone

Comment: Is there an url to test this with?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is private one .. I just need to know how to use WaitAttribute property in selenium.

Comment: It looks good to me. Have you looked into IsDisplayed ?

Comment: I have added a waiting line for two seconds then I found it works fine .. so it is just waiting step after clicking the element